# What do I replace SetDelegate with for audio?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to this website and I'm new to Xcode and I need help with the following codes:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
```

Gives me a warning saying " 'setDelegate' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0"

```
@property(assign) id<AVAudioSessionDelegate> Delegate NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(4_0, 6_0);
```

Gives me a warning saying " 'setDelegate' is has been explicitly marked deprecated here"

Comment: So, how are setDelegate and _executing, _finished relevant here ?

Comment: I was wondering if both issues could be corrected, however the setDelegate is the main issue because the app fails to build.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about failing to read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen for yourself, AVAudioSessionDelegate is deprecated.
If you read the documentation, you are directed to use notifications instead.

[image]

You can observe the following notifications:

```
AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification
AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereLostNotification
AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification
AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification
```

Here is a link to AVAudioSession Class [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/602958/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html).

If you still wish to use the deprecated code, you'll need to change the minimum required iOS Version for your target (deployment target) to iOS 5 but be warned that in newer iOS version your app could be broken!

[image]

Comment: Sorry I'm new to all of this, so what would I replace this code line with or how would i correct it? [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];

Comment: Your comment is beyond the scope of your initial question. You can change your deployment target to iOS 5 so no modifications are needed (but don't expect your code to run on > iOS 6). If you don't know how to change the code you have to use notifications, I suggest you start learning Objective-C and Apple's SDK.